# BASIC runtime error. Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined

Tags: macros, libreoffice, basic

What I'm trying to do is to count the average of some cells on the Macro of LibreOffice Calc...
By this code:
    REM  *****  BASIC  *****

```
Private Sub myrange()
myrange = Range("G31:G42")
Range("H45") =  WorksheetFunction.Average(myrange)

End Sub
```

I got the error:
    BASIC runtime error.
    Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to average the cells G31:G42 and insert the result in cell H45 then the following macro may helps you:

```
Private Sub myrange()
Dim Doc, myrange, sheet As Object

Doc = ThisComponent
sheet = Doc.Sheets(0)
sheet.getCellRangeByName("H45").Formula = "= AVERAGE(G31:G42)"
End Sub
```